# No array filter found for identifier 'element' in path

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update the `notifications` property from `false` to `true` by using MongoDb's `arrayFilters`.

[image: This is what the array/object looks like]

This is what I have tried:

```
  '$set':
    {
     
      "userObject.$.notificationsArray.$[element].notifications"  : true
    },  

  }), { arrayFilters: [{"element": 'e8b7589f-cc72-4fb3-a38b-855ae1106ab2'}] }
```

but I keep getting this error: **No array filter found for identifier 'element' in path 'userObject.$.notificationsArray.$[element].notifications'**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't use images for code/data/errors/stack traces/etc. - just include them in a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire document model isn't shown in the question, but perhaps this is enough to show how to use `"arrayFilters"` for the task.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 0
},
{
  "$set": {
    "userObject.notificationsArray.$[current].notifications": true
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "current.chatroom": "e8b7589f-cc72-4fb3-a38b-855ae1106ab2"
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RAS0doCV5Wn).